# Angular, object always empty in html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an object 'waypointIcon' and when I log it into console from ts file, it's full, but when i try put into html, its always empty. No errors in the console, HTTP request is a 200 in the browser network inspector.

nextFive array is normally working and show in html but waypointicon is still empty...

[image: console log of icon in ts file]

ts file:

```js
    public waypointIcon: Icon = new Icon();
    filtersLoaded: Promise;

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private iconsService: IconsService) {
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.httpClient.get('assets/w_bosses.json').subscribe(data => {
          this.bossesFromJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          this.getEventualBosses();
          this.sortAndFindNextFive();
        });
        this.iconsService.getWaypointIcon().then(icon => {
          this.waypointIcon = icon;
          console.log(this.waypointIcon);
          this.filtersLoaded = Promise.resolve(true);
        });
      }
```

html file:
<code

```html
<div *ngIf="filtersLoaded | async" class="card shadow">
  <div class="sub-card">
    <h2 class="card-title">Event timer</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Boss</th>
        <th scope="col">Zona</th>
        <th scope="col">Waypoint</th>
        <th scope="col">Čas</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let boss of nextFive">
        <th scope="row">{{boss.name}}</th>
        <td>{{boss.zone}}</td>
        <td>{{this.waypointIcon.id}}</td>
        <td>{{boss.time}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<p *ngIf="filtersLoaded | async">{{this.waypointIcon.id}}</p>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console or network inspector? Are you sure the HTTP request completes successfully? Does it work if you hard-code data rather than trying to fetch it? Etc. etc.

Comment: Http request require observables

Comment: Getdata(): Observables<any[]>{this.httpClient.get<any[]>('assets/w_bosses.json')   }

Comment: Then ngOnInit(){this.Getdata().subscribe(data => {
          this.bossesFromJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          this.getEventualBosses();
          this.sortAndFindNextFive()}

Comment: `<td>{{waypointIcon.id}}</td>` instead of `<td>{{this.waypointIcon.id}}</td>`